# Can we print ourselves?

Tags: biology, technological-development

Imagine if I can scan my physical body and store the data into a computer, then I can interact with other digital copies of people from any part of the world. (provided the anti-virus don't erase me first or block by my own firewall)

The most interesting part of this idea is you can use 3D printing technology to create copies of me based on my blueprint. (for now ignore ethical issue)

I believe in near future MRI will be able to scan object with more details down to sub-atomic level and print living organs. (seriously please ignore religious and legal issues)

**Question**

How hard is it to be able to print a living exact copy of myself?

Comment: Are answerers supposed to assume that you are correct and sub-atomic printing is in the near future, or are they supposed to evaluate that claim and tell you if they see any problems with it?

Comment: @sumelic see this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/new-3d-bioprinter-to-reproduce-human-organs/) I'm thinking if we can print living organs maybe we can print a brain.

Comment: @user6760 There's a huge difference between "making another organ whose DNA matches mine" and "making a living exact copy of myself."  Which side of that line are you looking towards?

Comment: But look at this quote: "Each capillary is less than a quarter the diameter of a human hair, making them difficult to work with, so they rely on the ability of the cells to self-assemble into these small blood vessels." When all you care about is making a working organ, you don't have to worry about the cellular level--living tissues can grow and adjust themselves automatically to some extent. But to copy the *information* in a brain, we'd need a much finer level of copying.

Comment: I agree with sumelic.  They're doing awesome things with that research... just not necessarily the things needed to copy the information in a brain

Comment: @sumelic I mentioned down to sub atomic level shouldn't that qualify as a much finer level of copying?

Comment: Well, it would; I'm just saying that that article doesn't indicate that it will be possible anytime soon. That was the reason for my first question, which you never answered: do you want the respondants to your question to assume that we will have these sub-atomic printing capabilities in the near future, however unrealistic it might seem, and then evaluate if it is possible with this technology to copy a person, or do you want input on the realism of the sub-atomic-printing part as well?

Comment: @sumelic I want to know if this is feasible in near future or perhaps distance future.

Comment: Two problems.  First, the copy can't be exact, due to the uncertainty principle.  Second, even if you could make a copy as nearly exact as allowed by physics, it still wouldn't be you.  Or rather, you'd have two different individuals arguing about which was the 'real' you :-)

Comment: As it stands, this question appears off-topic and not about worldbuilding. You could rephrase it and turn into a reality-check where your world *has* this technology and you want to know whether it's realistic - you'd get similar answers and the question would be on topic. I'm voting to close for now; if you rephrase and want me to have another look just ping me here.

Answer (score 1):

The Question is... If I take a detailed snapshot of a person at a particular instance of time, and record every aspect of their existence, all the way down to the energy, momentum, vector and spin of each smallest sub atomic particle, what will that picture contain?

Will it contain their memories?  What about their dreams?  Will the picture love the people that it's subject loves?  Will that picture contain the essential spark of life or is that spark seperate, absent from even such an exhaustive recording?

How big would that recording be?  I would guess that it would be substantially larger than the person whose picture was taken.  When you reduce the contents of a page of text to a collection of each ascii characters which appears on the page, it will take up less space on a harddrive than the original piece of paper.  But if you scan that page at 1 million dots per inch, the hard drive space needed to capture that same page grows substantially.  At a billion dots per inch, it grows even more.  How many dots per inch are needed to capture a person's favorite meal from the vibratory patterns of the atoms in their brain?

Better get a big hard drive!  I mean really big!  Maybe, Douglas Adams' [Deep Thought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) big.

Now for the printing...  @CortAmmon has already identified the primary problem which is that a living human body is quiescent.  Every part of it must come into being simultaneously, with every sub-atomic energy, momentum, vector and spin rendered not only perfectly but also harmoniously with those of every other sub-atomic particle.  It has to be a single perfect moment of creation, or you will never get all those independently moving quarks adequately synchronized.

Now on to the printing!  The only thind I can think of, which can handle this level of complexity and the need for simultaneous construction is something I call, a Divine Bomb.  It is an explosive, so perfectly calibrated for its point of detonation that at some moment following its ignition, a portion of its expulsed particles ricoche back on just the right vector, with just the right energy and spin, that when they collide upon some predefined intersecting point in some specific microsecond, they all take exactly the right place and path within the pattern to collectively form the printed whole, exact in every aspect, a perfect copy of the original.

So apparently, your going to need a planet for a hard-drive and a big-bang for a printer.  I'm not even going to speculate about the cpu or input devices, but their specifications will definitely wow all of your nerd friends.

...and even when you've got all the components gathered together, it is still not certain if your printed product will be a living human being or just an ugly bag of mostly-water.  Will the spark be present, or will you have pawned a galaxy to finance the creation of a lifeless corpse.

Personally, if you want more people around, I would suggest the classic approach to creating them.  It is no where near as expensive as what I have described here, and it is a lot more fun.

Comment: Definitely +1 for that last paragraph :-) I would have awarded a second one if i could for the answer as a whole. And a third for your "Divine Bomb". Nice idea!

Comment: If you can create a Big Bang, why limit the hard drive to planet-size?

Comment: I was trying to stay on a budget. ;^)

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to print ourselves with any technology this side of high-science-fiction.

The biggest issue is that the human body is not quiescent.  While you are printing it, it will start metabolizing and such.  This could easily expose the body to the harsh reality that it is half completed.

There are two approaches I see that could allow 3d printing of a human body

1. We find a previously unknown switch that makes the human body quiescent.  Cold temperatures might do well at this, but we don't yet know any way to bring a body that cold to be scanned, construct a copy, then bring it back from those temperatures without damage.
2. We take a more organic approach, and try to create structures that grow from the inside out, rather than trying to print from to bottom.  However, this may be as complicated as unlocking the meaning of life.

Note: trying to copy a mind is still a philosophical question, and may call for even more extreme methods of scanning and printing.  It is yet unknown whether the electrical signals in the brain are our "self," or if they're just riding on top of the "self" that matters.

Comment: Oh really you'r saying it can't be done and I've already put all my money into [the human brain project](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Brain_Project) thinking I can backup my mind into cloud server.

Comment: @user6760 Rule #1 of IT: Always test that you can actually restore the system from the backups.  They are not really backups until you are confident you can restore them :)

Comment: @user6760: If you think the Human Brain project has anything to do with backing yourself up on a server, you are much mistaken.  It's about simulating small parts of the brain in order to try to understand how it works.